# request_irq to be handled by a single CPU

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I would like to ask if there is a way to register the interrupt handler so that only one cpu will handle this interrupt line.
The problem is that we have a function that can be called in both normal context and interrupt context. In this function we use `irqs_disabled()` to check the caller context. If the caller context is interrupt, we switch the processing to polling mode (continuously check the interrupt status register). Although the `irqs_disabled()` tells that the local interrupt of current CPU is disabled, the interrupt handler is still called by other CPUs and hence the interrupt status register are cleared in the interrupt handler. The polling code now checks the wrong value of the interrupt status register and do wrong processing.

Comment: You haven't really given us enough information to answer the question.  We don't even know what kind of processor this is.

Comment: Hi @RobertHarvey, it is an ARM multicore processor. I apologized that I cannot tell the exact name of the ARM core. May you please suggest if Linux has a generic way to configure this kind of interrupt delivery. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Don't limit your interrupt to be handled by a single CPU - instead use a spin_lock_irqsave to protect the code path. This will work both on the same CPU and across CPUs.

See http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/spinlocks.txt for the relevant API and here is a nice article from Linux Journal that explain the usage: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5833

Comment: Hi @gby, may you please explain a little bit on how do we use spin_lock to protect the concurrency in this case? Is there any issue if we use the `spin_lock_irqsave()` inside the interrupt handler? I just wonder if some other code already takes the lock, the CPU which handles the interrupt will be hung inside the interrupt handler. Many Thanks!

Comment: @dien The interrupt handler will wait until the other CPU releases the lock. Read chapter 5 of [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/).

Comment: @dien The Linux device drivers link is really the best answer indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I've got no experience with ARM, but on x86 you can arrange for a particular interrupt to be called on only one processor via /proc/irq/<number>/smp_affinity - set from user space - replacing the number with irq you care about - and this looks as if it's essentially generic. Note that the value you set it to is a bit mask, expressed in hex, without a leading 0x. I.e. if you want cpu 0, set it to 1, for cpu 1, set it to 2, etc.  Beware of a process called irqbalance, which uses this mechanism, and might well override whatever you have done.

But why are you doing this? If you want to know whether you are called from an interrupt, there's an interface available named something like in_interrupt(). I've used it to avoid trying to call blocking functions from code that might be called from interrupt context.

Comment: Never mind the second part of this - I think I misread your question. Reading it again, I think you are saying that you don't just need the code to behave correctly when called from an interrupt context, you need to not have the interrupt handler called on some other processor while another copy of the interrupt handler is doing this polling thing. If so, in_interrupt() isn't going to solve the problem - and you are probably already using it.